# How to restore iPhone using laptop

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

So I erased my iPhone but my Home button broke off after dropping it. Is there any way to restore it through my laptop?

When I click on restore nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you able to successfully connect the iPhone to your laptop?

Comment: it's connected but I do not know how to proceed to restore the iphone using a backup through the laptop

Comment: As you mentioned you have erased it. Now if it connected to your laptop, iTunes should prompt you to either set as new or restore from backup. Can you see that? Is there any step you are stuck on?

Comment: i clicked restore but nothing happened

Comment: Try setting it up as a new device instead. You can attempt to restore from backup later. Also, after finishing the setup (it won't require the use of Home button at any point), you can immediately enable assistive touch. This way you'll be able to use a software Home button whenever required.

Comment: it just erased it

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: it just restored it by erasing the data. I still need to reset it on my phone i guess